# gluonfx / javafx native windows 10 - mvn gluonfx:run works but mvn:gluonfx:nativerun throws NPE and running .exe does not show controller behaviour

Tags: javafx, gluonfx

I have a simple javafx application called Sample that shows the current time. It has a controller like that

SampleController.initialize()

```
        Timeline clock =
                new Timeline(
                        new KeyFrame(
                                Duration.ZERO,
                                e ->
                                {
                                    lblTime.setText(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
                                }),
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1)));
        clock.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        clock.play();
```

The application runs perfectly in my IDE when started from a launcher class (not extending javafx.application.Application) that has in it's main method:

```
        Sample.main(args);
```

I can build that application (not the launcher class) using maven with mvn gluonfx:build without any complaints. I can also run

`mvn gluonfx:run`

successfully. However if I run

`mvn gluonfx:nativerun`

I see NPE inside the controller class.

If I run the .exe file generated by maven the application starts but does not show the controller behaviour (formatted output of current time every second). It does not complain about anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Run `mvn gluonfx:runagent`, explore the application, and then try `mvn gluonfx:build gluonfx:nativerun` again. If you still have exceptions, post them.

Comment: yessss!!! mvn gluonfx:runagent did it!!! thanx a lot!!!